# Directory.GetFiles Method Not Working In VB

Tags: vb.net, directory, getfiles

I have created software with Visual Builder that cleans up your desktop. I have used the Directory.GetFiles method to move file types into certain directories. When I first coded it worked fine although I then got an error saying `System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` Which I am not sure how to fix as I create the directory for the files with separate buttons as seen in the code.

I am also having issues with the other buttons which may be a result of the other error. When I go to clean the shortcuts which I programmed to move .lnk files into a Shortcuts folder none of them move into that folder unless they have previously been in that folder.

Full Code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Desktop Cleaned")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim filePaths = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.png")

        For Each filePath In filePaths
            Dim filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
            Dim newPath = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Pictures", filename)

            IO.File.Move(filePath, newPath)

        Next filePath

        Dim filePaths2 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.jpg")

        For Each filePath2 In filePaths2
            Dim filename2 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath2)
            Dim newPath2 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Pictures", filename2)

            IO.File.Move(filePath2, newPath2)

        Next filePath2

        MessageBox.Show("Pictures Compiled And Cleaned")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim filePaths3 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.lnk")

        For Each filePath3 In filePaths3
            Dim filename3 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath3)
            Dim newPath3 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Shortcuts", filename3)

            IO.File.Move(filePath3, newPath3)

        Next filePath3

        Dim filePaths6 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.url")

        For Each filePath6 In filePaths6
            Dim filename6 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath6)
            Dim newPath6 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Shortcuts", filename6)

            IO.File.Move(filePath6, newPath6)

        Next filePath6

        MessageBox.Show("Shortcuts Compiled And Cleaned")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


        Dim filePaths4 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.mp4")

        For Each filePath4 In filePaths4
            Dim filename4 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath4)
            Dim newPath4 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Videos", filename4)

            IO.File.Move(filePath4, newPath4)

        Next filePath4

        Dim filePaths5 = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.avi")

        For Each filePath5 In filePaths5
            Dim filename5 = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath5)
            Dim newPath5 = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Videos", filename5)

            IO.File.Move(filePath5, newPath5)

        Next filePath5

        MessageBox.Show("Videos Compiled And Cleaned")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(
"C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Shortcuts")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(
"C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Videos")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(
"C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Pictures")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error Code

`IO.File.Move(filePath, newPath)` Returns The Error,

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim filePaths = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\", "*.png")

        For Each filePath In filePaths
            Dim filename = IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
            Dim newPath = IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users\bj\Desktop\Pictures", filename)

            IO.File.Move(filePath, newPath)

        Next filePath
```

Error Message : `System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include all the [exception details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Also, kindly make sure that your code follows the guidelines of a [repro].

Comment: That is the whole exception detail, I have also showcased the part that returns the error now.

Comment: It's not the GetFiles that isn't working though- so the question title is a bit incorrect.. ;)

Comment: "none of them move into that folder unless they have previously been in that folder" - can you explain this in a bit more detail? I never heard of windows refusing to move a file into a folder unless it had recently been removed from that folder

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah I'm not sure how either, I have it setup to move all .lnk files into a folder and when I first ran the program it moved most of the .lnk files although did leave some. When I ran the program again it still didn't move these files, I put one of the .lnk files into the folder and the back onto the desktop and when I ran the program the file moved when I ran the program. Not sure if this has to do with the file or not but I'd have to assume so.

Comment: I think I'd be using a command prompt to check that the files really didn't move or whether it's  a weird caching bug/ restart your machine etc. I occasionally have a situation where I drag files with explorer and they move but don't look like they have.. it's like explorer gets out of sync with the disk contents

Comment: I have found that there are two paths leading to the desktop, one is a Public Desktop and one is my user desktop. A few of my shortcuts were located in the Public Desktop and not on my user desktop which is why they were not being moved. The reason it worked when they were put in a folder and then back on the desktop is that I was relocating them to my user desktop from the public desktop. I'll just write some extra code that grabs .lnk from the public desktop aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the documentation for File.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8) - the example code checks if the file exists first and deletes it

Wa can extend this logic to maybe make for a nicer experience.

```
If IO.File.Exists(newPath) Then
    Dim dr = MessageBox.Show($"File {newPath} exists, do you want to keep both files? The recently moved file will have a number added to its name", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

    Select dr 
      Case DialogResult.Cancel
        Continue 'go to next loop iteration

      Case DialogResult.No
        IO.File.Delete(newPath)

      Case DialogResult.Yes 'keep both

        'Make the path eg kitten.1.jpg, kitten.2.jpg until we find a free name
        Dim x = 0
        Do
          x += 1
          newPath = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(newPath, i & IO.Path.GetExtension(newPath))
        While IO.File.Exists(newPath)

    End Select

End If
```

Comment: Would this slot in between `IO.File.Move(filePath, newPath)` and  `Next filePath` ?

Comment: Can I leave you to think a bit more about that one? Take a read of the documentation; where did they do their File.Exists check - before or after the Move that crashes if the file already exists? Where does logic dictate you want to do a file-exists-in-new-location check- before the call that crashes if it does exist, or after you move the file? What happens if you check for the existence of a file at a particular path after you've moved a file to that path, and if you find a file there (because you just moved a file there) ask the user if they want to delete it?

Comment: Alright, I have got that sorted out now. I am now faced with two other issues that are probably quite simple, `Do must end with a matching loop` and `While must end with a matching End While`. I understand that I have to add a `loop` and an `End While` although not sure where these go. Visual Studio suggested a fix which was just putting the 'loop' under 'Do' and 'End While' under 'While'  when doing this the software crashes when I click 'Yes' to keep both files.  Another issue that has shown is that 'i' has not been declared, I can define it as nothing but I'm sure it has a purpose right?

Comment: Ah, that's just because I made a syntax error when writing my Do loop. It's only missing the word "loop" before the while. Without this vb thinks the word "while", which is supposed to be part of the Do loop, is a separate while loop hence the two errors

Comment: You can read more about Do loops in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement)

Comment: Oh ok, and so what about `newPath = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(newPath, i & IO.Path.GetExtension(newPath))` returning the error `'i' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level.` The code still crashes when I click 'Yes' to keep all files which may be related to this error?